# Check if a string contains any amount of numbers followed by a specific letter [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

To be specific, I'm trying to find degrees in strings. For example, I'd like to be able to find the degree in a string that might look something like "blahblah 3c blah blah blah". And if it's possible, I'd like to be able to save it to a string.

Some pseudocode of what I'm thinking

```
a1 = "asdasdas 33F asdasdasds" 
if a1 has int followed by 'F','f','C','c':
    a2 = "33F"
```

Sorry if this is impossible, or if I didn't explain it well enough. I am quite new to python. I was able to come up with the following:

```
if any(str.isdigit(c) for c in a1) and any(('F','f','C','c')):
```

But that can work even if the int and the letter aren't connected, like "asdadsc 3 asdasddas". Is any of this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the module re (Regular expression or Regex)

Comment: Go with regex `\d+[FfCc]{1}`

Comment: `any('F','f','C','c')` does not do that you think it does. Do some reading on the use of `any` and `all`. It will help.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful replies everyone. I appreciate it a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple RegEx variant would be:

```
import re

a1 = "asdasdas 33F asdasdasds asdasdas 33C asdasdasds asdasdas 33c asdasdasds asdasdas 33f asdasdasds"

result = re.findall("\d{1,3}[FfCc]", a1) # finds groups of 1, 2, or 3 connected digits followed by any one of 'F', 'f', 'C', or 'c'
print(result)
```

Comment: You only search for `F` in your regex, you forgot `f`,`C` and `c`. Also, no one said degrees are maxing at 999.

Comment: Hey thanks! I combined this with Igle's comment and it 100% worked. This is exactly what I was needing. I spent far too long trying to figure this out on my own, lol. Learned quite a bit though fortunately, and thanks for introducing me to RegEx.

Comment: I added 'f', 'C', and 'c' to the list. And no, no one (including me) said degrees are maxing at 999 however 1234567890123456677863665212321313213F  presumably isn't a degree so `\d+` isn't the solution either. @Jertyu You're welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a1 = "asdasdas 33F asdasdasds"
degree = re.search(r"(?P<degree>[0-9]+F)",a1).group("degree")
```

Comment: Why this much complicated regex. \d+F is enough

Comment: Are you referring to the `[0-9]`, or the `P<degree>` as the complicated part ? I guess `[0-9]` vs `\d` is just personal preference no real reason. But I really prefer to name regex groups. It makes the regular expression so much more readable than using `\1` `\2` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use module re (Regular expression or Regex). re.search() will scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern.

example

```
import re
b = re.search('\d+<following_letter>', a1)
print b.group(0)
```

For your example:

```
import re
b = re.search('\d+F', a1)
print b.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do it with `RE` (regular expressions)

Here is simple example with test string:

```
import re

regex = r"\d+(F|f|C|c)" # regep itself

test_str = ("asdasdas 33F asdasdasds\n"
    "sdfasd 333c sadfsdaf\n"
    "asdfasd 33f asdfasd 33C 33F 33c ")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for match in matches:
    print ("{match}".format(match = match.group()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `re` module ?
`

```
import re
degrees_re = re.compile('\d+\W')
degres_re.findall("asdasdas 33F asdasdasds")
Out[4]: ['33F']
```

Or just for Celsius and Fahrenheit:

```
degrees_re = re.compile('\d+\[CFcf]')
```